# php mysql username password verification

Tags: php, mysql

I want to know the error on this php coding, just wondering where is the mistake in this coding I skipped html part for page input design as I want to know the php part only,
, Im trying to use this for users to enter the username and password to login to the website and this particular website should be password protected password

```
<?php>
if isset($_POST=['submit']));
{
$inputuser = $_POST['user'];
$inputpass = $_POST['pass'];

$user = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "Tutorial";

$connect = mysql_connect("localhost",$user,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or ("database not found");

$query = " SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE 'user' =                             i   $inputuser";//for query specific data
$querypass = "SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE 'user' =            $        i   $inputpass'";

$result = mysql_query($query);
$resultpass = mysql_query($querypass);

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$rowpass = mysql_fetch_array($resultpass);

$serveruser = $row["user"];
$serverpass = $row["password"];

if($serveruser&&$serverpass){
if (!$result) {
die("username and password is invalid");
}

echo "<br> <center>database output</b></center><br><br>";
mysql_close();
echo $inputpass;
echo $serverpass;
if ($inputpass == $serverpass) {
header('location: Home.php');
} else {
header('location: fail.php');
}
}
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? Could you be a little more specific with the issue ?

Comment: please stop using `mysql_*` functions as these are deprecated

Comment: You should set your error reporting on E_ALL and remove the error suppressing on the connection with your database. You want the errors to be printed, and we would like to see your errors :)

Comment: This is an incredibly insecure way to log a user in - DO NOT use this in production. You're vulnerable to sql injection and you're clearly not hashing your passwords either.

Comment: Thanks all , addicted 20015, the error recieved was Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\tutorial\connect.php

Answer (score 0):

try this way:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='" . mysql_real_escape_string( $inputuser ) . "' AND psw='" . mysql_real_escape_string( $inputpsw ) . "'";
$qr=mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($qr)>0) //admitting that usernames and psw are unique
{
  //success
  header('location:home.php');
}
else //no rows=no username responding to $inputusername
{
  header('location:fail.php');
}
```